# I can't create a cookie using node-client-sessions

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies

I am building a NodeJS web server, mostly static files (jade to come) but I am at the point where I want to be able authenticate the user and all was going fine until I hit a speed bump with setting cookies.

I am using express & client-sessions and I am almost verbatim example code.
No matter what I am doing I don't seem to be able set a cookie.

Code below I am hoping there's a simple gotcha I have missed!

** Versions **
NodeJS: v 6.2
client-sessions: 0.7.0

```
//** Required files
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var sessions = require("client-sessions");
var app = express();
var port = 8080;
var svr = app;

//** Middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public')); //** Use express globally to catch all requests and direct to Public folder
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})); // create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // create application/json parser
app.use(sessions({
  cookieName: 'mySession', // cookie name dictates the key name added to the request object
  secret: 'kdheiuehiygft', // should be a large unguessable string
  duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // how long the session will stay valid in ms
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5 // if expiresIn < activeDuration, the session will be extended by activeDuration milliseconds
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    req.mySession.seenyou = true;
    res.setHeader('X-Seen-You', 'false');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.htm");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reasons appears to be that Express was "capturing" the input prior to me setting anything and redirecting to the index.html file in Public.

Having now created a separate login page which POST's the data to a new route, all works fine!